# Storing an Object in a Database

Tags: python, sql

I have little to no experience with databases and i'm wondering how i would go about storing certain parts of an object.

Let's say I have an object like the following and steps can be an arbitrary length. How would I store these steps or list of steps into an sql database?

```
class Error:
   name = "" #name of error
   steps = [] #steps to take to attempt to solve error
```

Comment: This is a very broad question. How you store those steps depends on how you set up your database.

Comment: Why not pickle instead of a database? The format of your data does not warrant the use of a SQL database, not really applicable for NoSQL either.

Comment: At present this question can't be answered. Are/Can you use an ORM? What flavor of SQL (MSSQL, MySQL, Postgres etc)? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to decide how i should set up the database. The basic idea is to have errors that have steps that will attempt to solve the error tied to them.

Answer (score 0):

For your example you would create a table called Errors with metadata about the error such as an error_ID as the primary key, a name, date created, etc... then you'd create another table called Steps with it's own id, lets say Step_ID and any fields related to the step.  The important part is you'd create a field on the Steps table that relates back to the Error that the steps are for we'll call that field again error_ID, then you'd make that field a foreign key so the database enforces that constraint.

Comment: So then to ensure that the steps get executed in the correct order would I just have another field in the steps table that corresponds to which step number it is for the corresponding error? Seems like a waste of space but might just be the best option.

Comment: Sure, you'd have a field called step_order or something like that.

Comment: That's really about the most basic example of relational data modeling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your Python objects in a database (or any other language objects in a database) the place to start is a good ORM (Object-Relational Mapper). For example Django has a built-in ORM. [This link](http://www.pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-vs-orms/) has a comparison of some Python Object-Relational mappers.